# How do I calculate the normal of a plane defined using homogeneous coordinates?

Tags: 3d, mathematics, normals

I can define a plane in 3D space using three 3D points (`p0`, `p1`, `p2`) that all lie in the plane and that form a non-degenerate triangle. Calculating the normal of the plane is as simple as calculating the cross product of any two non-parallel 3D vectors that lie in the plane, for instance `(p1 - p0)` and `(p2 - p0)`. So far, so good.

But what if I use homogeneous coordinates for my points? How do I find the normal of the plane then? Of course, if all points have `w != 0`, I could simply normalize them (divide by `w`) and treat them as regular 3D points. But what if one or more points have `w == 0`?

The way I see it, there are three possible answers to this question:

1. *You do it the same way.* If so, please explain how to calculate the cross product of two 3D vectors defined using homogeneous coordinates.
2. *You do it some other way.* If so, please explain how.
3. *You can't, your question makes no sense and you are clearly confused.* If so, please explain why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do it the same way, basically. You just need to get rid of the divisions by zero.

First of all, there is no solution if `w0=w1=w2=0`. This degenerate case should be handled as if all points were aligned (because in a sense, they are, at infinity).

Let us assume, without loss of generality, that `w0!=0`. If not, just swap `p0` and `p1` for instance.

Here is how you would do it when no `w` is zero: divide the 3-dimensional points by their respective `w` value, then take a cross-product of the vectors you mention:

```
     |x0|         |x1|         |x2|
p0 = |y0|    p1 = |y1|    p2 = |y2|
     |z0|         |z1|         |z2|

q0 = p0/w0   q1 = p1/w1   q2 = p2/w2

v = (q2 - q0) × (q1 - q0)
  = (p2/w2 - p0/w0) × (p1/w1 - p0/w0)
  = 1/(w2*w1) (p2 - p0 w2/w0) × (p1 - p0 w1/w0)
```

But wait, if this vector `v` is normal to the plane, then obviously `v` multiplied by `w1*w2` is still normal to the plane! So here is another vector that works:

```
v' = (p2 - w2/w0 p0) × (p1 - w1/w0 p0)
```

This one involves no division by zero and is therefore safe to take to the `w1=0`, `w2=0` or `w1=w2=0` limits.

Comment: Thank you for writing out all the steps in the derivation of `v'`, it really makes it easier to understand.

Comment: However, I don't understand why there is no solution when `w0 == w1 == w2 == 0`. I understand why the math doesn't check out, because of the division by zero, but I thought that a plane defined by the points `(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0), (0,0,1,0)` (using order `(x,y,z,w)`) would have the same normal as one defined by `(1,0,0,1), (0,1,0,1), (0,0,1,1)`. Perhaps my intuition about a point at infinity is incorrect? Can you help me understand?

Comment: @sarnesjo it is true that if you take points `(1,0,0,w)`, `(0,1,0,w)`, `(0,0,1,w)` with `w>0` then the normal vector is `(1,1,1)` and it doesn't appear to be affected by the value of `w` so one may think pushing `w` to the limit `0` will yield a normal vector of `(1,1,1)`. However it is illegal to calculate the limit of a three-variable function by fixing a relationship between the variables.

Comment: @sarnesjo take for instance points `(1,0,0,w)`, `(0,1,0,w)`, `(0,0,1,2w)`. At `w=0` they become the same points as before. However, their normal vector is now `(1/2,1/2,1)`. You can see there is an inconsistency here! It's because the limit of a multivariate function is only valid if it is not affected by the “path” the different variables take. There is [another example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariable_calculus#Limits_and_continuity) on Wikipedia.